# Ошибка при чтении файла в виртуальном окружении: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 139687: invalid continuation byte

Tags: python, pandas, utf-8, virtualenv

Коллеги, помогите разобраться с кодеками при чтении файла. Я открываю виртуальное окружение virtenv, запускаю jupyter notebook и пытаюсь прочесть файл csv (код ниже). При чтении файла выдает ошибку:

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xd3 in position 139687: invalid continuation byte

Когда этот же файл запускается в jupyter notebook без виртуального окружения - ошибок никаких нет!

Сам код чтения файла:

```
  df_requests = pd.read_csv(open('Request_limits_pendings.csv', 'r'), sep = ';', dtype={'Req Tp Eh Id':str,'Req Ctr Local Ext Nr':str},  parse_dates = ['Req Tp Grade Man Dt', 'Req Tp Grade Auto Dt'])
df_requests.head()
```

Буду признателен за помощь!

Comment: В какой кодировке сохранен файл? Пробовали указать ‘encoding=“cp-1251”’ ?

Comment: Сохранялось не мной, я получил файл, но высока вероятность что utf-8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Кодировка UTF-8, которая *применяется по умолчанию* к параметру `encoding` функции `pd.read_csv()`, есть кодировка *с переменным количеством октетов (т.е. байтов)* для индивидуальных символов (знаков).

Количество октетов определяется по *начальным битам первого октета* - не начинается единицей - один, две единицы - 2, три единицы - 3, четыре единицы - 4:

```
+-------------+----------+-------------------------------------+
| Количество  | Значащих |               Шаблон                |
|  октетов    |    бит   |                                     |
+-------------+----------+-------------------------------------+
|       1     |      7   | 0xxxxxxx                            |
|       2     |     11   | 110xxxxx 10xxxxxx                   |
|       3     |     16   | 1110xxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx          |
|       4     |     21   | 11110xxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx 10xxxxxx |
+-------------+----------+-------------------------------------+
```

Второй, третий и четвёртый октет называется *байтом продолжения (continuation byte)* и **нужен начинаться с `10`**, что тоже назунаено в таблице.

Но ваш октет `0xd3`, двоично `11010011`, не начинается с `10`, т.е **он не может быть байтом продолжения.**

Но байт продолжения **ожидался**, потому что ваш предыдущий байт *наверняка не был последним байтом кодировки предыдущего символа.*

Значит, кодирование не удовлетворяет стандарту UTF-8, который - я повторяю - применяется по умолчанию к параметру `encoding` функции `pd.read_csv()`. Т.е. ваш файл кодирован по другому кодеку (вероятно с одним октетом для всякого знака).

Потому нужно в параметре `encoding` задать другую кодировку - «угадать её» (что вы уже правильно сделали).

Comment: Спасибо, очень познавательно!

Answer (score 2):

Проблема решилась следующим образом - encoding='ISO-8859-1':

```
df_requests = pd.read_csv(open('Request_limits_pendings.csv', 'r', encoding='ISO-8859-1'), sep = ';', dtype={'Req Tp Eh Id':str}, 
             parse_dates = ['Req Tp Grade Man Dt', 'Req Tp Grade Auto Dt'])

df_requests.head()
```